# Bugsnag via segment not showing any error in their dashboard

Tags: react-native, crash-reports, segment, error-reporting, bugsnag

I've integrated bugsnag in react native via segment and followed all the steps provided by segment documents but still, it's not showing any sort of error or log in bugsnag dashboard. Should I implement bugsnag directly instead of relying on the segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would always recommend integrating with Bugsnag directly instead of using the Segment integration. This is because Bugsnag should be loaded as early on in your application as possible in order to detect all errors in your app, and using it via the Segment integration breaks that.

The Segment integration also doesn't use an up to date version of Bugsnag - by integrating with Bugsnag directly you will be able to use the latest version of the Bugsnag library and take advantage of all the latest fixes and improvements.

Take a look at our platform guides for details on how to get set up with your preferred platform: https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/

Comment: App crashing after adding bugsnag directly in react native @bugsnag